# Combine conditions in oracle full-text search

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to implement a full-text search in Oracle, but I don’t understand how to create a search query correctly?

The task is as follows:

1. If I'm writing a word, all entries should be displayed and sorted by relevance. In this case, when my query contains "word", the search results should display "dddwordddd", "word", "wordddd" and "dddword" sorted by relevance.
2. If I'm writing several words in a search query, the result containing both all the words and some of the query should be displayed. Also sorted by relevance.
3. And it should be possible to unite words in groups. For example,
   when I conclude words in quotation marks(or any other wrapper, like "/" or "["), such entry must be searched for strictly, without separate search by words.

I was able to implement only a part of this, using the `ABOUT` operator. It is ideally suited for the second item of the task. If I write a query like:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), name 
from table 
WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'ABOUT('some text')', 1) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;
```

then I'll get the following results:

```
some text
some
text
```

But how can I to combine it with search in a phrase (without separate search by words), and with a search of partial occurrences (like `%word%`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's load up a table with example text:

```
create table t (
  c1 varchar2(100)
);

insert into t values ( 'some text' );
insert into t values ( 'some' );
insert into t values ( 'text' );
insert into t values ( 'exact phrase text' );
insert into t values ( 'phrase text' );
insert into t values ( 'exact phrase text word' );
insert into t values ( 'exact some wordddd phrase ' );
insert into t values ( 'phrase exact text dddword' );

commit;

create index i 
  on t ( c1 )
  indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

1) You can use wildcards to search for strings within strings:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), c1 
from   t
WHERE  CONTAINS( c1, '%word%', 1 ) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;

SCORE(1)   C1                           
         5 exact phrase text word       
         5 phrase exact text dddword    
         5 exact some wordddd phrase
```

If you want to prioritise text that contains the exact string "word", use OR to search for an exact match. To ensure precise matches rank higher, you can also weight this term by "multiplying" it with the weight operator:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), c1 
from   t
WHERE  CONTAINS( c1, '%word% or word*2', 1 ) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;

SCORE(1)   C1                           
        11 exact phrase text word       
         5 phrase exact text dddword    
         5 exact some wordddd phrase
```

2) The ABOUT operator searches for related terms or phrases. For example, you could use this to return documents including "string" when you search for "text". If you want to search for text that includes any words from a list, OR them together:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), c1 
from   t
WHERE  CONTAINS( c1, 'some OR text', 1 ) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;

SCORE(1)   C1                          
         3 some text                   
         3 text                        
         3 phrase exact text dddword   
         3 phrase text                 
         3 exact phrase text word      
         3 exact phrase text
```

3) To find a particular phrase, enter the exact phrase in your contains:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), c1 
from   t
WHERE  CONTAINS( c1, 'exact phrase', 1 ) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;

SCORE(1)   C1                       
         4 exact phrase text word   
         4 exact phrase text
```

If you're searching for text that includes any combination of the above searches, you could try stuffing them all into a single CONTAINS call. But it's easier to OR separate calls to CONTAINS. Supply a new value for the third parameter for each. Then you can get the score for it by passing the same value to SCORE:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), SCORE(2), SCORE(3), 
       SCORE(1) + SCORE(2) + SCORE(3) tot_score,
       c1 
from   t
WHERE  CONTAINS( c1, 'exact phrase', 1 ) > 0 
OR     CONTAINS( c1, '%word% or word*2', 2 ) > 0 
OR     CONTAINS( c1, 'some or text', 3 ) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) + SCORE(2) + SCORE(3) DESC;

SCORE(1)   SCORE(2)   SCORE(3)   TOT_SCORE   C1                           
         4         11          3          18 exact phrase text word       
         0          5          3           8 phrase exact text dddword    
         4          0          3           7 exact phrase text            
         0          5          0           5 exact some wordddd phrase    
         0          0          3           3 text                         
         0          0          3           3 some text                    
         0          0          3           3 phrase text
```

If you want to know more, check out the [CONTAINS query operators](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-6410B783-FC9A-4C99-B3AF-9E0349AA43D1) in the docs.